# What does ISKCON think of the Dharma Shastras?

Tags: scripture, dharma-shastras, iskcon

We know that some modern sects of Hinduism like the Arya Samajis and others reject the Dharma Shastras to some extent, so what's the stance of ISKCON in all this?

Comment: @SK how? Isn't iskon a part of Hinduism? Isn't the DharmaShastras a part of Hinduism?

Comment: See its website's post about the Dharma Shastras [here](https://iskconeducationalservices.org/HoH/tradition/doctrine-and-scripture/smriti-the-dharma-shastras/).

Comment: Iskcon follows their own gauda vaishnava philosophy which is simply  their interpretation of the major hindu scriptures. Their interpretation may or may not be the actual truth.

Comment: @TheCrimsonUniverse so what is there interpretion or the Dharma Shastras (like if they reject it or accept it)?